# problem: how to reference to objects/variables created in decorator from injected method?

Tags: python, reference, decorator

I encountered a problem with the availability of objects created within the decorator, and needed in the `test_case` method. My code presenting below:

```
def execute_results_navigation(test_case):
    def wrapper(self,*args,**kwargs):
        result=Result()
        pagination=Pagination()
        results_page_index=1
        while results_page_index<=pagination.get_pages_number():

            for results_object_index in range(results.get_objects_number_per_single_page()):
                test_case(self,*args,**kwargs)

                pagination.set_active_page_number(results_page_index)
            results_page_index+=1

    return wrapper
```

In place of `test_case` method is "injected" the following code (everything takes place using predefined decorator):

```
@execute_results_navigation
def test_check_availability_of_search_results(self):
    """
    test case 2.22
    """
    offer=Offer()

    result.select_hotel(results_caller["button"],results_object_index)
    offer_price=offer.get_offer_object_details().price
    offer.verify_offer_availability(offer_price)
    offer.back_to_search_results()
```

`test_case` method has no access to `result`,`pagination` objects and `results_object_index` variable. All objects have been initialized when calling the decorator. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with this method, but I thought that these instances exist within the `wrapper` method and access to them should not cause problems.

Comment: Are you seeing run-time issues, or are you just concerned about "compile errors"

Comment: It's a run-time issue. Just in place, when I referencing to objects created in decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to access local variables defined in wrapper within test_case.

Looks like test_check_availability_of_search_results is an instance method, so one way to solve your problem is to assign those variables to attributes of 'self'.